# How to load KnockoutJS custom functions with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have a View Model that uses a custom observableArray function for sorting. When I try to run this it says: "...has no methods 'sortByProperty'".

How should I load the handlers.js file to make this work?

**handlers.js:**

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
        'use strict';

        ko.observableArray.fn.sortByProperty = function (prop, order) {
            this.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
                var result;
                if (obj1[prop] == obj2[prop])
                    result = 0;
                else if (obj1[prop] < obj2[prop])
                    result = -1;
                else
                    result = 1;

                return order === "desc" ? -result : result;
            });
        };

    });
```

**viewmodel.js:**

```
define([
        'knockout',
        'js/extends/handlers'
    ], function(ko) {
        'use strict';

        var LabelsModel = function() {
            var self = this;

            self.availableLabels = ko.observableArray();
            self.selectedLabel = ko.observable();
            self.sortBy = ko.observable(); // What field to sort by
            self.sortOrder = ko.observable(); // Sort order. asc or desc.

            // Returns the labels for the current page
            self.pagedRows = ko.computed(function() {
                // Sorts the labels
                return self.availableLabels.sortByProperty(self.sortBy(), self.sortOrder());
            });

        };

        return LabelsModel;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first make sure KnockoutJS is defined, then load the plugins, and finally launch your application. This I think is how all plugins for libraries should be loaded. Here is how you can do it:

```
require.config({
        paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery-1.9.0.min',
        ko: 'libs/knockout-2.2.1.min'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'ko'], 
    function($, ko) {
        // ensure KO is in the global namespace ('this') 
        if (!this.ko) {
            this.ko = ko;
        };

        requirejs(['handlers'],
            function () { 
                require(['app'], 
                    function(App) { 
                        App.initialize(); 
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I had a lot more libraries so I cut it down a bit only to JQuery and KnockoutJS, but basically you:

1. declare where your libraries
2. require loading them
3. require loading the plugins for your libraries, here the handlers for KnockoutJS
4. load your app (conveniently named... 'app' here :-). This is where you should initialize your view models and bind them to DOM elements. This is most likely the point where all libraries and plugins have been loaded.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make it global for your particular scenario. It seems like your original sample should work properly. That is the way that I load extensions.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Could you add your own answer ? I found that way of doing it in a Git of John Papa I think and it worked for me because I had a lot of libraries. I'd really like to know to how it could be more simple.

Comment: For external libraries that are not AMD ready, making KO global is one  option, although shim config is usually the way to go with current require.js.  For this particular scenario, I am just more curious why it did not work originally, as it just adds to the same `ko` object available in both places.

Comment: So I went back and did some more testing. And it looks like @RPNiemeyer was right - it was already working. I think the problem was cacheing. So i added require.config({ urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()}); and it worked.